# How can I get apps in a docker network to talk with apps outside

Tags: docker, networking

I have a situation where a system is made of quite a few clients and servers, all talking with each other.

It was developed locally with each server listening on a different port.

Now is time to put this in production, with an important fact: apps may be shuffled around and sometimes will live on the same computer and sometimes not.

The only solution that made sense at this stage is to have each app be addressed by its name and use a reverse proxy on each machine.

So, if there are x computers and each of them has a reverse proxy, some of the tools, and the dns is properly setup, it will all work.

Where it will start to break down is when debugging comes into play:
I still need to simulate the whole environment locally at times, with docker.
And if I have a server running locally in the debugger, I can't find a good solution for the services running in docker to talk to it.

One option would be to also have a reverse proxy on the local machine, but this is going to turn into hell very quickly.

Has anyone faced that problem before and came up with a good solution?

Comment: Answer a question for me, would you: why? Docker and containerization were introduced to create a separate environment. The main point is to _separate_ host from containers. And now you want to connect outside to the inside, completely destroying the idea of environment segregation. What is the point? Either put everything into Docker, or just remove Docker from the picture.

Comment: the main reason is debugging.. I need to be able to substitute pars of the running system with instances run in a debugger for testing.

Comment: sounds more like azure service fabric. all the facilities provided by ASF is being created manually here(loadbalancer, shuffling of apps, local cluster for debugging). Not sure if it is worth the effort.

Comment: if I run everything through docker-compose, it works; I just need to be able to substitute any element with one from a debugger instance

Comment: Are you looking for suggestions for a multi-host Docker-based setup, or specific suggestions on debugging around the proxy-based setup you've described?

Comment: debugging can be done on a single host at this stage; so one of the services can run within VS or Rider, while the others need to be in their docker containers